# Is BIgQuery the right backend for a reporting GUI?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I understand bigquery is great for querying massive amounts of data. What I am not so sure of is its responsiveness for a reporting GUI.
Lets say I am building something like Google Analytics. And need to store and query page view data with certain dimensions/filters.
And I need to expose this web app GUI to a customer, so the response time has to be < couple of seconds. This is not an internal dashboard where I can wait for 20 seconds to see a chart rendered. Speed/responsiveness is the most important deciding factor.
Is this a use case addressed by BigQuery? If not, please suggest workarounds/alternate backends. I'd prefer a cloud based data storage, real time querying solution.
My customer level data may be a few MBs or may be few 100s of MBs in the future but not GBs for sure.

Comment: I for one tend to use BQ + Datastudio for pretty much every dashboard I  create at our company. If speed is an issue I usually create some pre-calculated table and query from there but this is rarely the case (Datastudio also caches results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is only going to be on the order of ~100 MB, you're better off using Cloud SQL.  BQ is great for ~TB/PB datasets.